# How do I have this code scale both axes in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, graph

One of my tasks is to make graphs of data for presentations. I found this code which has been very helpful to me in scaling the y-axis on my charts but I would like to configure it so that it scales both axes. My issue is I am unable to identify how the code is distinguishing from y vs x in the first place.

```
Sub AdjustVerticalAxis()

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim srs As Series
Dim FirstTime  As Boolean
Dim MaxNumber As Double
Dim MinNumber As Double
Dim MaxChartNumber As Double
Dim MinChartNumber As Double
Dim Padding As Double

  Padding = 0.1  'Number between 0-1

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    
      FirstTime = True
      
      For Each srs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
          MaxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(srs.Values)
        
          If FirstTime = True Then
            MaxChartNumber = MaxNumber
          ElseIf MaxNumber > MaxChartNumber Then
            MaxChartNumber = MaxNumber
          End If
        
          MinNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(srs.Values)
          
          If FirstTime = True Then
            MinChartNumber = MinNumber
          ElseIf MinNumber < MinChartNumber Or MinChartNumber = 0 Then
            MinChartNumber = MinNumber
          End If
        
          FirstTime = False
      Next srs
      
      cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber * (1 - Padding)
      cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxChartNumber * (1 + Padding)
  
  Next cht

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I tried reading up on the how to do this and compared other codes that perform similar functions but `Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber` seems to be the most common solution.

Comment: [This may be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.axes)

Answer (score 1):

This should work to scale both axes:

```vb
Sub AdjustAxes()
    Const PADDING As Double = 0.1
    Dim cht As ChartObject, srs As Series, FirstTime As Boolean
    Dim MaxY As Double, MinY As Double, MaxX As Double, MinX As Double
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        FirstTime = True
        For Each srs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
            'track max/min Y/X values across series
            SetMinMax srs.Values, FirstTime, MinY, MaxY
            SetMinMax srs.XValues, FirstTime, MinX, MaxX
            FirstTime = False
        Next srs
        'resize axes
        With cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue)
            .MinimumScale = MinY * (1 - PADDING)
            .MaximumScale = MaxY * (1 + PADDING)
        End With
        With cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory)
            .MinimumScale = MinX * (1 - PADDING)
            .MaximumScale = MaxX * (1 + PADDING)
        End With
    Next cht
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub SetMinMax(vals, bFirstSeries As Boolean, ByRef MinVal As Double, ByRef MaxVal As Double)
    Dim mn, mx
    mn = Application.Min(vals)
    mx = Application.Max(vals)
    MinVal = IIf(bFirstSeries, mn, Application.Min(mn, MinVal))
    MaxVal = IIf(bFirstSeries, mx, Application.Max(mx, MaxVal))
End Sub
```